# How to symmetricize this nxn Identity matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider the following code :

```
I=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & & & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
```

Which outputs this nxn Identity matrix :
[image]

The issue I have is that this matrix doesn't look quite symmetrical as I thought it should be, I hope someone can help me out fix this tiny issue that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots,xdots/shorten=4pt]
1 & 0 & & \Cdots & & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \Ddots & & & \Vdots \\
\Vdots &  \Ddots & \Ddots \\
\\
  &   & &        & & 0 \\
0 & \Cdots & & & 0 & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Well noted! thank you

Comment: I suppose that in answer you already use the version 5.9 ;-) . Your tempo of package development is incredible ... +1!

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, I use version 5.9... (but for this answer, v. 3.13 is enough).

Answer (score 3):

One more with `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[
\mathbf{I} =
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1   &       & \Block{2-3}<\huge>{0} \\
    &   1   &        &      &       \\
    &       &   1    &      &       \\
\Block{2-3}<\huge>{0}
    &       &       & \Ddots    &   \\
    &       &       &      &   1   \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really love this package, I find it more aesthetic than the default matrices.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ I=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots& & & \ddots &   \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably some package (or newcommand) you are using. You have too many dots in `\cdots`, `\vdots` and `\ddots`, and because that the symmetry is lost. In the following code I have your matrix (I_1, with just 3 dots per command) and another matrix I_2. The latter is what I'd do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[I_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\
0      & 1      & 0      & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0      & 0 \\
0      & \cdots & 0      & 1      & 0      & \vdots \\
\vdots &        &        & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0      & \cdots & 0      & \cdots & 0      & 1
\end{bmatrix},\quad I_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\
0      & 1      & 0      & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\
0      & 0      & 1      & \cdots & 0      & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 1      & 0 \\
0      & 0      & 0      & \cdots & 0      & 1
\end{bmatrix}.\]
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I will take note, thank you very much for your answer sir!